# I can't open data/data in ddms, but it's okay by the adb shell

Tags: android, adb, ddms

I have root my phone and by using the CMD and ADB shell, I can see everything under the data/data. But in ddms's file explorer the data file can't be opened neither can I set lng or lat. so it's quite uncomfortable . The phone's debugMode is on there's nothing wrong when I use ddms several months ago in windows. But now I can't operate by ddms in mac.

Comment: I've test many phones and the result is same.But the avd works fine.Is it because google don't want the developers to see or operate the other apps' data so easily then put some rules?

Comment: I‘ve found the  problem.It's about the file access. First of all,you need to make the data file available:use adb shell and then su ."chmod 755 /data".the you can see  every packet. But you still cann't see the db or sp.Then make the directory you wanna see available:"chmod -R 777 com.*"

Comment: good that you found the problem! Please post it as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

I‘ve found the problem.It's about the file access. First of all,you need to make the data file available:use adb shell and then su ."chmod 755 /data".the you can see every packet. But you still cann't see the db or sp.Then make the directory you wanna see available:"chmod -R 777 com.*"